# Local Sync and force imports of Perforce

Tags: perforce

Could you explain what does this phrase mean:

"Within your changelist, select the sc.p4sm file and use the
contextmenu P4SyncManager/Sync **(use local, force imports from local
hard disk)** to get the set of files from the perforce."

What does mean:

1. use local
2. force imports from local hard disk

And which commands line flags responsible for these parameters?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the P4SyncManager documentation?  It's a third-party tool so i don't know exactly how it works, but I might be able to guess if I could look through the rest of the doc.  For some reason Googling it isn't turning up any sort of official download page.

Comment: One way to determine what command line flags are being issued by a certain tool is to run the command against a server with command logging enabled (P4LOG and server=1 configuration enabled), and then look at the actual commands that the server received in the server's log.

Answer (score 0):

For others that may wonder regarding P4SyncManager.

This tool is specific to Harman/Becker corporation and is not distributed outside company.

Comment: oh, that's why.